# JQuery not working on all pages of Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Im kinda "new" to JQuery, I've been working on a big brand with many websites. So I came up with a JQuery Toggle menu to ALL of those sites.

I've got a single menu file called menu.html with the Toggle, CSS and the HTML on it, and I add it to all the pages with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menuTop").load("/menu/menu.html");
});
```

The main problem is JQuery working greatly on FF and Chrome, and on some pages of IE9. BUT it doesnt work on some pages properly, and I have no idea why.

For example:

www.coldwell-fiscal.com.br works greatly on all browsers but www.coldwell.com.br works on a strange way, the menus doesnt toggle or toggle strangely at all.

I tried check the codes between pages, added some no.conflict on the toggle, so it would stack with another libs and plugins.

Here is the code to the toggle:

```
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("li#showColdwell").click(
            function() {
                if ($j("ul.single").css("display")=="none") {
                    $j("ul.single").slideDown();
                    $j("li#showColdwell").addClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleColdwell").addClass("toggleHover");
                }
                else {
                    $j("ul.single").slideUp();
                    $j("li#showColdwell").removeClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleColdwell").removeClass("toggleHover");
                }
            }
        );
        $j("li#showColdwell").click(
            function() {
                $j("ul.empresas, ul.aplicativos, ul.serv, ul.tecnologia, ul.mais").slideUp();
                $j("li#showEmpresas, li#showApp, li#showServ, li#showTec, li#showMais").removeClass("slide");
                $j(".toggleEmpresas, .toggleAplicativos, .toggleServicos, .toggleTecnologia, .toggleMais").removeClass("toggleHover");
            }
        );
        $j("li#showEmpresas").click(
            function() {
                if ($j("ul.empresas").css("display")=="none") {
                    $j("ul.empresas").slideDown();
                    $j("li#showEmpresas").addClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleEmpresas").addClass("toggleHover");
                }
                else {
                    $j("ul.empresas").slideUp();
                    $j("li#showEmpresas").removeClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleEmpresas").removeClass("toggleHover");
                }
            }
        );
        $j("li#showEmpresas").click(
            function() {
                $j("ul.single, ul.aplicativos, ul.serv, ul.tecnologia, ul.mais").slideUp();
                $j("li#showColdwell, li#showApp, li#showServ, li#showTec, li#showMais").removeClass("slide");
                $j(".toggleColdwell, .toggleAplicativos, .toggleServicos, .toggleTecnologia, .toggleMais").removeClass("toggleHover");
            }
        );
        $j("li#showApp").click(
            function() {
                if ($j("ul.aplicativos").css("display")=="none") {
                    $j("ul.aplicativos").slideDown();
                    $j("li#showApp").addClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleAplicativos").addClass("toggleHover");
                }
                else {
                    $j("ul.aplicativos").slideUp();
                    $j("li#showApp").removeClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleAplicativos").removeClass("toggleHover");
                }
            }
        );
        $j("li#showApp").click(
            function() {
                $j("ul.single, ul.empresas, ul.serv, ul.tecnologia, ul.mais").slideUp();
                $j("li#showColdwell, li#showEmpresas, li#showServ, li#showTec, li#showMais").removeClass("slide");
                $j(".toggleEmpresas, .toggleColdwell, .toggleServicos, .toggleTecnologia, .toggleMais").removeClass("toggleHover");
            }
        );
        $j("li#showServ").click(
            function() {
                if ($j("ul.serv").css("display")=="none") {
                    $j("ul.serv").slideDown();
                    $j("li#showServ").addClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleServicos").addClass("toggleHover");
                }
                else {
                    $j("ul.serv").slideUp();
                    $j("li#showServ").removeClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleServicos").removeClass("toggleHover");
                }
            }
        );
        $j("li#showServ").click(
            function() {
                $j("ul.single, ul.aplicativos, ul.empresas, ul.tecnologia, ul.mais").slideUp();
                $j("li#showColdwell, li#showEmpresas, li#showApp, li#showTec, li#showMais").removeClass("slide");
                $j(".toggleEmpresas, .toggleAplicativos, .toggleColdwell, .toggleTecnologia, .toggleMais").removeClass("toggleHover");
            }
        );
        $j("li#showTec").click(
            function() {
                if ($j("ul.tecnologia").css("display")=="none") {
                    $j("ul.tecnologia").slideDown();
                    $j("li#showTec").addClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleTecnologia").addClass("toggleHover");
                }
                else {
                    $j("ul.tecnologia").slideUp();
                    $j("li#showTec").removeClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleTecnologia").removeClass("toggleHover");
                }
            }
        );
        $j("li#showTec").click(
            function() {
                $j("ul.single, ul.aplicativos, ul.serv, ul.empresas, ul.mais").slideUp();
                $j("li#showColdwell, li#showEmpresas, li#showServ, li#showApp, li#showMais").removeClass("slide");
                $j(".toggleEmpresas, .toggleAplicativos, .toggleColdwell, .toggleServicos, .toggleMais").removeClass("toggleHover");
            }
        );
        $j("li#showMais").click(
            function() {
                if ($j("ul.mais").css("display")=="none") {
                    $j("ul.mais").slideDown();
                    $j("li#showMais").addClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleMais").addClass("toggleHover");
                }
                else {
                    $j("ul.mais").slideUp();
                    $j("li#showMais").removeClass("slide");
                    $j(".toggleMais").removeClass("toggleHover");
                }
            }
        );
        $j("li#showMais").click(
            function() {
                $j("ul.single, ul.aplicativos, ul.serv, ul.empresas, ul.tecnologia").slideUp();
                $j("li#showColdwell, li#showEmpresas, li#showServ, li#showApp, li#showTec").removeClass("slide");
                $j(".toggleEmpresas, .toggleAplicativos, .toggleColdwell, .toggleServicos, .toggleTecnologia").removeClass("toggleHover");
            }
        );                                  
    });
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have two event handlers for the clicks on the same element selector?

Comment: I didn't understand your question Mark, Im really new to JQuery. Could you highlight the code?

Comment: for instance you have this twice: `$j("li#showColdwell").click(` with some code after each one, they both handle the same event.  There are others like this.

Comment: Oh, the second .click works around without if/else condition.
The first if/else will work only if the current item is not on dropdown state, while the second .click works to clean those open dropdowns without alternating his state

Comment: Your second page is producing errors in the swapImages and swapText funcitons: "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the first lines in each function.

Comment: How am I supposed to fix this? I dont get this clearly. I mean, it works on dozens of pages on IE, and then a few doesnt work... Its the same lib, the same code, I just dont get it.

Comment: If you turn OFF (for test) the swapImages and swapText functions on that page, does that make your menu work correctly?

Comment: Mark, I managed to make it work on other pages. It was more a CSS Position - Z-Index trouble more than the JQuery itself. Thanks for your attention, really.

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace all that with this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var mySlide = $j("ul.single, ul.empresas, ul.aplicativos, ul.serv, ul.tecnologia, ul.mais");
    var mySlideClass = $j("li#showColdwell, li#showEmpresas, li#showApp, li#showServ, li#showTec, li#showMais");
    var myToggleClass = $j(".toggleColdwell, .toggleEmpresas, .toggleAplicativos, .toggleServicos, .toggleTecnologia, .toggleMais");
    function actions(ck, tg, t) {
        if (ck.css("display") == "none") {
            ck.slideDown();
            t.addClass("slide");
            tg.addClass("toggleHover");
        } else {
            ck.slideUp();
            t.removeClass("slide");
            tg.removeClass("toggleHover");
        }
        mySlide.not(ck).slideUp();
        mySlideClass.not(t).removeClass("slide");
        myToggleClass.not(tg).removeClass("toggleHover");
    }
    $j("li#showColdwell").click(function() {
        var ck = $j("ul.single");
        var tg = $j(".toggleColdwell");
        var t = $(this);
        actions(ck, tg, t);
    });
    $j("li#showMais").click(function() {
        var ck = $j("ul.mais");
        var tg = $j(".toggleMais");
        var t = $(this);
        actions(ck, tg, t);
    });
    $j("li#showEmpresas").click(function() {
        var ck = $j("ul.empresas");
        var tg = $j(".toggleEmpresas");
        var t = $(this);
        actions(ck, tg, t);
    });
    $j("li#showApp").click(function() {
        var ck = $j("ul.aplicativos");
        var tg = $j(".toggleAplicativos");
        var t = $(this);
        actions(ck, tg, t);
    });
    $j("li#showServ").click(function() {
        var ck = $j("ul.serv");
        var tg = $j(".toggleServicos");
        var t = $(this);
        actions(ck, tg, t);
    });
    $j("li#showTec").click(function() {
        var ck = $j("ul.tecnologia");
        var tg = $j(".toggleTecnologia");
        var t = $(this);
        actions(ck, tg, t);
    });
});
```

Comment: Should I do anything other than just switching this script?

I tried just replacing and it didnt work.

Comment: The reason I did this this way, was to combine the event handlers so that only one is active at a time - and the processing is in one function. Thus the slideup/down on ck occurs then the other slideup. It SHOULD also be faster as I cache lists at the top.  IF you add dynamic content used here, might have to change to use `.on()` click handler.  SO, try this then provide feedback.

Comment: I would like to know what did NOT work exactly as the logic should be the same (if I made no mistakes or bad assumpions) - might have to see some markup/ and/or an example page.

Comment: See my comment on the question regarding errors on the second page - those might be the root of your issue.